# Google app engine (path file)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, puppeteer

I am trying to get google app engine to work using node.js and puppeteer

It runs fine on local dev and node.path there is just dir **/ index.html** and pupeteer can run it.

However when I deploy it as app engine flexible, it suddenly makes the path **/app/index.html** ans obviously puppeteer can't read it like it could in node.

Will update the question with code once I get home and not using phone.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just answering when having the code by hand to have immediately a complete question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running your application in Google App Engine with Flexible environment. What Flex does is to dockerize your application. At least for python the application is then placed in the `/app` directory, which is [not unheard of](https://blog.realkinetic.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-python-applications-37d0272c52f3) for when executing python in Docker.

You can read more it in the official Google's GitHub repository for ['gcr.io/google_appengine/python'](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime) source for more details.

**Note:** you can [debug the running Flex instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance) or even download the [container built for your application](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/).